# ScrollView squashes contents

Tags: android, scrollview

I'm trying to add a scroll view to this activity since it does not fit all on one screen at once. I've done it the same way I did it for another activity and that one worked. However this time whenever I add the ScrollView to the XML all the elements in the preview get squashed up together at the top

**Original XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/sidebar" layout="@layout/sidebar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />



        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.jacksteel.comp4.New_Journey"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
            <include android:id="@+id/tool_bar" layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="12"
                android:id="@+id/NJTitle"
                android:hint="@string/NewJourneyTitleHint"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="text|textCapSentences"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:backgroundTint="#989898"
                android:textColorHint="#989898"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_below="@+id/NJTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/NJStartinglblText"
                android:id="@+id/NJStartingLbl"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/NJTitle"
                android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/DepartDatelbl"
                android:textColor="#0084ff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/destination_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:elevation="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:textColor="#0084ff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/DepartDatelbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ColourChooser"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:elevation="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/NJDestinationlblText"
                android:id="@+id/Destinationlbl"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NJStartingLbl"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NJStartingLbl" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/destination_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Destinationlbl"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ColourChooserbuttonText"
                android:id="@+id/ColourChooser"
                android:background="@drawable/button_border"
                android:layout_below="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textColor="#0071dc"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/departlabel"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/NJDepartOnlblText"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/DepartDatelbl"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/departlabel2"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/departlabel2Text"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/departlabel"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/departlabel"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Original Appearance:**

[image: without scroll view]

Then after adding the ScrollView around the RelativeLayout it looks like this:
[image: with scroll view]

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

**Edit: XML with ScrollView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/sidebar" layout="@layout/sidebar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:context="com.jacksteel.comp4.New_Journey"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
            <include android:id="@+id/tool_bar" layout="@layout/tool_bar"/>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="12"
                android:id="@+id/NJTitle"
                android:hint="@string/NewJourneyTitleHint"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:inputType="text|textCapSentences"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:backgroundTint="#989898"
                android:textColorHint="#989898"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <fragment
            android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_below="@+id/NJTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/NJStartinglblText"
                android:id="@+id/NJStartingLbl"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/NJTitle"
                android:layout_marginStart="41dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/DepartDatelbl"
                android:textColor="#0084ff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/destination_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:elevation="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:textColor="#0084ff"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/DepartDatelbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ColourChooser"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:elevation="3dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/NJDestinationlblText"
                android:id="@+id/Destinationlbl"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NJStartingLbl"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/NJStartingLbl" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/destination_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Destinationlbl"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/ColourChooserbuttonText"
                android:id="@+id/ColourChooser"
                android:background="@drawable/button_border"
                android:layout_below="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textColor="#0071dc"

                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/departlabel"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/NJDepartOnlblText"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/DepartDatelbl"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/departlabel2"
                android:textColor="#989898"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/departlabel2Text"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/DepartTimelbl"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/departlabel"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/departlabel"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Just curious. Why do you need a ScrollView? A LinearLayout scrolls when its children exceed its boundaries

Comment: because it's a RelativeLayout, or do they do that too? Just using one because that was the answer i got from some googling

Comment: Is the ScrollView height set to android:layout_height="match_parent"? You should probably post the XML that is actually causing you problems.

Comment: yeah both the ScrollView height and width are set to match_parent. i have added the XML with the ScrollView

Comment: @krislarson still no luck finding a solution, any ideas?

Comment: I started looking at it and I can see a bunch of problems with the layout.  This is what I do in these situations:  I comment out all the widgets inside the `RelativeLayout`.  Then *one by one*, I add each widget back in by moving the start of the comment.  I look at what's wrong with that widget, fix everything, and when it looks right, I go uncomment the next one. And don't just look at it in the preview and say "oh that looks right"! Go through each of the widget relationships and make sure they are set up  correctly.

Comment: Two problems I see:  ScrollView says layout underneath the toolbar, but toolbar is *insde* the ScrollView, so I don't really know if you want the toolbar to scroll or not.  Also the widget "NJDestinationlblText" has `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`. That can't possibly be right, take that out and put in the align/above/below layout it needs.

Comment: @krislarson I've fixed it, thanks. Not sure what exactly was causing it but i went through and manually edited all the XML positions instead of letting them get auto generated by the designer.

Comment: @Jack yeah, I can't trust that thing.  I edit everything manually and see how it looks in the designer.